# Returning only latest result from LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, sql, left-join

I am querying data from two tables (students2014 and notes2014) in order to return a list of students along with notes on each student. To do this I am using the following select statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM students2014 
LEFT JOIN notes2014 
ON students2014.Student = notes2014.NoteStudent 
WHERE students2014.Consultant='$Consultant' 
ORDER BY students2014.LastName
```

This successfully gives me a list, however students with more than one note appear twice, for e.g:

- Student a - Note
- Student a - Note
- Student b - Note
- Student c - Note

etc...

I only want the latest note to appear for each student, thus delivering a list of each student only once.

Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the studends table with a sub query. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `students2014`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `note`, `NoteStudent`
    FROM `notes2014`
    HAVING `NoteID` = MAX(`NoteID`)
    GROUP BY `NoteStudent`
) `notes`
ON `students2014`.`Student` = `notes`.`NoteStudent`
WHERE `students2014`.`Consultant`='$Consultant' 
ORDER BY `students2014`.`LastName`
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't. Each note has a unique ID called NoteID which is an incremental numerical figure therefore latest note has higher ID number. Is it possible to work with that?

Comment: @PhilHowell Ok, have changed the query. It now uses the `NoteID`. If it is an `auto_increment` as you say then it should work

Comment: I had tried HAVING NoteID = MAX =(NoteID) but that doesn't appear to work...

Comment: What means not work? means you receive no results? If so, can you execute just the sub query to see what it returns?

Comment: Sorry, yes. There are no results I'm afraid.

Comment: can you execute just the sub query to see what it returns?

Answer (score 0):

Try (I don't test it, but must work):

> ```
> SELECT *, MAX(notes2014.notesID) as maxnoteid 
> FROM students2014 
> LEFT JOIN notes2014 ON students2014.Student = notes2014.NoteStudent
> WHERE students2014.Consultant='$Consultant' AND notes2014.notesID = maxnoteid 
> GROUP BY students2014.ID
> ORDER BY students2014.LastName
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  *
from
  `students2014`,
  `notes2014`
where
  `students2014`.`Student` = `notes2014`.`atudent`
  and `notes2014`.`id` in (
    select
    'NoteStudent`,
     max('NoteID`) as`MaxID`
  from
    `notes2014`
  group by
    `NoteStudent`
  )`
```